# reCAPTCHA in Smart Capture form

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, smart-capture

I'm trying to implement reCAPTCHA in Smart Capture form, but when I'm trying to submit the form nothing happens, and form data is not captured in the DE. If I remove the reCAPTCHA code it works fine.
Can we use reCAPTCHA in smart capture?[image]

Comment: Without significantly hacking SmartCapture, I don't see how you'd use reCAPTCHA. reCAPTCHA uses a server side validation of the token that gets sent along with the form post. You can implement this in CloudPages, for sure. But I don't think SmartCapture's what you're after to implement the form and the server-side script that'll handle the post and validate the token.

Comment: If you are trying to implement reCAPTCHA by google, then here is the link to go https://ampscript.xyz/how-tos/how-to-implement-google-recaptcha-on-marketing-cloud-forms/ by [Ivan Razine](https://www.linkedin.com/in/ivanrazine/)

Comment: @VishalKumarCV: I already referred that link. I want to implement for smart capture. Not for custom form.

Comment: reCAPTCHA uses client side script that you can implement in a SmartCapture form, but you need to validate the post on the server side. This isn't supported by SmartCapture and without validating the request there's not a lot of point implementing reCAPTCHA in the first place.